# Add spacing inbetween the bars in a grouped bar- chart with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, spacing

my current code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def create_grouped_bar_chart():
    # Daten für die Balken
    groups = 3
    bar_width = 0.35
    x = np.arange(groups)
    values1 = [2, 3, 4]  # Werte für die ersten 2 Balken
    values2 = [4, 5, 2]  # Werte für die nächsten 2 Balken

    # Balkendiagramm erstellen
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    
    # Ersten Balken jeder Gruppe mit Streifen versehen (hatch)
    bar1 = ax.bar(x, values1, bar_width, label='Beschriftung 1', hatch='///', edgecolor='black', color='white')
    bar2 = ax.bar(x + bar_width, values2, bar_width, label='Beschriftung 2', edgecolor='black', color='gray')

    # Achsenbeschriftungen
    plt.xlabel('X-Achse')
    plt.ylabel('Y-Achse')
    
    # Achsenbereiche festlegen
    plt.ylim(0, 6)
    plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 7, 1))

    # X-Achse beschriften
    ax.set_xticks(x + bar_width / 2)
    ax.set_xticklabels(['Gruppe 1', 'Gruppe 2', 'Gruppe 3'])

    # Titel und Legende anzeigen
    plt.title('2D Balkendiagramm mit Gruppen')
    plt.legend()

    # Diagramm anzeigen
    plt.show()

create_grouped_bar_chart()
```

Is it possible to add spacing in between the two bars that are grouped together in each group? It looks a little bit weird when they are side by side like this.
Thank you very much :)

Comment: `ax.bar(x-gap/2, values1, ...)` and `ax.bar(x + bar_width + gap/2, values2,, ...)` with e.g. `gap = 0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def create_grouped_bar_chart():
    # Daten für die Balken
    groups = 3
    bar_width = 0.35 #Adjustable as needed
    x = np.arange(groups)
    values1 = [2, 3, 4]  # Werte für die ersten 2 Balken
    values2 = [4, 5, 2]  # Werte für die nächsten 2 Balken

    # Balkendiagramm erstellen
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    
#UPDATED HERE=================
    # Ersten Balken jeder Gruppe mit Streifen versehen (hatch)
    bar1 = ax.bar(x - bar_width/2, values1, bar_width, label='Beschriftung 1', hatch='///', edgecolor='black', color='white')
    bar2 = ax.bar(x + bar_width/2, values2, bar_width, label='Beschriftung 2', edgecolor='black', color='gray')

    # Achsenbeschriftungen
    plt.xlabel('X-Achse')
    plt.ylabel('Y-Achse')
    
    # Achsenbereiche festlegen
    plt.ylim(0, 6)
    plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 7, 1))

    # X-Achse beschriften
    ax.set_xticks(x)
    ax.set_xticklabels(['Gruppe 1', 'Gruppe 2', 'Gruppe 3'])

    # Titel und Legende anzeigen
    plt.title('2D Balkendiagramm mit Gruppen')
    plt.legend()

    # Diagramm anzeigen
    plt.show()

create_grouped_bar_chart()
```

This is an updated code to add scpace between grouped bars.

x coordinates of the bars for first group

```
"x - bar_width/2"
```

x coordinates of the bars for second group

```
 "x + bar_width/2"
```

bar-width is adjustable as needed.

Hope this helps.